# Change data remove after the parens

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

HI I have data in one column as this: 
in `SQL Server 2008`

```
Aetna (AETNA)
```

I need to update this so that it will be Aetna that is to remove everything after the first parens in an update mode.

Comment: This post shows no effort or research on your part.

Comment: replace would be for a string I want to change the contents of the columns

Comment: Where do you think replace would be used, if not to replace the string contents of a column?

Comment: but this is one by one, isn't there a way to do on the entire table? i want to keep all data until the first parens

Comment: is this something that can be done programmatically in SQL? In other scripting languages I would move the data into an array, I would move each element to an output col until the ( then I exit the loop.

Comment: @DwivediPrigot Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mention wanting to use update mode; could you provide an example of update statements you've tried and why you don't think they would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX()` to find the position of the `(`, then select everything to the `LEFT()` of that:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LEFT('Aetna (AETNA)',CHARINDEX('(','Aetna (AETNA)')-1))
```

Need to subtract 1 from the length to also remove the `(`, and `RTRIM()` removes any extra blank space from the right side.

Just replace the hardcoded string with your column name.

The update would be:

```
UPDATE table
SET col = RTRIM(LEFT(col,CHARINDEX('(',col)-1))
WHERE col like '%(%'
```

Comment: isn't RTRIM for a string?

Comment: It trims blank spaces from the right side of a string, yes.  This must be a string column if it is storing something like `Aetna (AETNA)`

Comment: thanks this is great. Can someone remove the -1 i fail to see what was so terrible this topic

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for all records:

```
update t
    set col = left(col, charindex(' (', col))
    where col like '% (%';
```

Comment: update [Programmer].[dbo].[GN_51-65_Rec]
    set [Pmt Amount] = left([Pmt Amount], charindex(' (', [Pmt Amount])
    where [Pmt Amount] like '% (%';
  have I entered correctly?
  I got an error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.